# python distutils: access to name of compiled extension

Tags: python, distutils

I use distutils to compile a swig-based extension module:

`python setup.py build_ext` produces the file `_my_module_ext.cpython-32m.so` (from a `.c` and a `.i` file). This name appears to depend on the python version used (in my case, it's python 3.2).

How can I access the name of this shared-object from within `setup.py` or even from within a module in the installed package?

The reason I need this is, that I have a separate, ctypes-based python-file that wants to load this file using `numpy.ctypeslib.load_library`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suffix is available through `sysconfig.get_config_var('SO')`. Read more about ABI-tagged shared libraries at [PEP 3149](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/).